# OpenAI API streaming response causes timeout on Heroku

Tags: heroku

I'm running a Python / Django app on Heroku which calls out to the OpenAI chat completions API. The frontend is a React app, also on Heroku. The frontend sends a request to the backend which then calls the OepnAI API, the backend receives the streaming response and streams it to the frontend.

The stream can take a long time (>30 seconds) to complete. It works fine locally. When running it on Heroku in production, after exactly 30 seconds I get an error `"[CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT"` in my logs and the stream errors out.

According to [this heroku article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout#long-polling-and-streaming-responses) the 30 second timeout should not apply to streaming requests and it should instead be a rolling 55 second window (which I'm well within).

However, it doesn't seem to be working. I tried both using OpenAI's python library and also by using `requests` directly:

```
url = "https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions"
    headers = {
      "Authorization": f"Bearer {OPENAI_KEY}",
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }

    body = {
        'model':'gpt-4-1106-preview',
        'messages':messages,
        'temperature':temperature,
        'stream':True
    }

    r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=body, stream=True)

    for line in r.iter_lines():
        if line:
             l = json.loads(line.decode("utf-8").split('data: ')[1].strip())
             yield l['choices'][0]['delta']['content']
```

Any idea how to make this work? When I just run it on the backend via a python console it takes more than 30 seconds but runs and completes fine, the error I see on the frontend is `host-rrweb-network.js:1     POST <...backend url...> net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING 200 (OK)`

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by adding `--keep-alive 3000 --timeout 3000` to my procfile